# change object name in loop inR

Tags: r, object, assign

I have a for loop which reads in a different RData file in each iteration and that works well with just paste.
However, once the RData file is loaded there is an object loaded called 
topy in the first instance of the loop, in the second it is ropy, then eopy and so on.
What I now tried is

```
vals<-c("topy","ropy","eopy")


paste("vals[i]")->r
```

to assign these different objects to r which is used further in the script and is overwirtten in every step of the loop. But that does not work. Topy and ropy and the rest ar matrixes.
When I load the RData file and then just type manually topy the matrix will be shown but if I do paste and then type r it will only show "topy". I also tried assign - did not work..any idea?

Comment: Can you show us the `for` loop?

Comment: just really need to know how to make paste() to write the name of a matrix not just the characters...dont really know why the for loop is relev

Comment: Well if there is something in that loop that you presume is overriding that `paste()`, the `for` loop should be the first thing to check. I may have missed your point though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I got your point, is the following what you need?

```
p <-parse(text=vals[i])
r <- eval(p)
```